# Exposing UUID or BIGSERIAL Primary Keys

Tags: databases, uuid

Exposing primary keys is bad practice. How should I expose UUID or BIGSERIAL Primary Keys to clients — hashing, encoding, encrypting? For integers there are libraries like hashids, what about UUID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UUIDs are just large integers written in a particular format. There are libraries that convert to and fro UUIDs, or you can check out answers such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40503321/convert-int64-to-uuid).

Once you have the integer, you can employ AES, or some reversible scheme such as a [Feistel network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feistel_cipher) or, if the user has no way of ever recovering the decrypted information, a simple XOR with a known secret.